# Python Generating Random Numbers in Loop Confusion

Tags: python, for-loop, random, set

I've been trying to print n random numbers based on a given in a range and storing it in a set, so I've been doing something like

```
for x in range(n):
  set1.add(randrange(0, n)
```

I want something like {6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 4} bc n = 6, but it ends up printing values between [1, 6] which is what i want, but it doesn't actually print just 6 values. What happened wrong here? Does setting randrange mess up the range in the for loop?

Should I be doing range(randrange(0, n)) instead?

Comment: sets cannot hold duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

A random number can end up being the same as a previous one causing you to have less values. Try using a while loop instead:

```
set1 = set()
n = 10

while len(set1) < 6:
    set1.add(randrange(0, n))
```

Or from looking at your question you just want the numbers in 1-6 shuffled? Try using random.shuffle:

```
from random import shuffle

numbers = list(range(1, 7))
shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Shouldn't randrange generate different numbers each time? This seems to generate the same sequence each time.

Comment: @cxspv2108 have you written something like `random.seed(<somenumber>)`? Note that random is actually psuedo random and uses a seed to generate the numbers etc. If you set the seed it would always give same results.

Comment: I haven't set a seed, so that's why i'm wondering why my code is printing the same thing.

Comment: Also sets are not ordered. So it doesn't matter how elements are added. You should use lists instead for that (likely the issue here).

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that python sets does not allow adding duplicated values. its better to use lists if you want to have duplicated values.

```
from random import randint
set1 = set()
list1 = list()
n = 6
for x in range(0,n):
    mynum = randint(0,n)
    set1.add(mynum)
    list1.append(mynum)

print(list1)
print(set1)
```